# Display the selected value radio button group in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, object

I would like to know how to display the object of selected value in radio button group using javascript,
I have two radio buttons group with default checked options,  how to display the object of checked radio buttons using javascript.

I have tried but got stuck, how to display the object based on radio button selection,

```
${obj.map.funtion((e)=>{
<div class="form-check" onClick=${(e)=>this.handleSelect(e,obj)}>
    <input class="form-check-input" name="sending" type="radio" value="bank transfer" Checked>
Bank Transfer
<br>
    <input class="form-check-input" name="sending" type="radio" value="credit">                                                                                       Credit Card
</div>});

handleSelect(e){
      const temp = obj.map(e => Object.entries(e).map(([k, val]) => val)).flat(2)
    var selectvalue = temp.filter(x=>x.in == selectvalue && x.id == id);  
    var defaultvalue = temp.filter(e=>
      e.id !== id && e.in==e.target.value
    )

}
```

```
var obj = [{
    "btob": [{
      "id": "trans",
      "in": "bank",
      "out": "bank",
      "value": 10
    },{
      "id": "fund",
      "in": "bank",
      "out": "bank",
      "value": 10
    }],
    "ctob": [{
      "id": "trans",
      "in": "credit",
      "out": "bank",
      "value": 20
    },{
      "id": "fund",
      "in": "credit",
      "out": "bank",
      "value": 10
    }]
}]
```

```
Expected Output:
  //if(radio 1(trans) is credit and radio 2(fund) is bank transfer)

[{
      "id": "trans",
      "in": "credit",
      "out": "bank",
      "value": 20
    },

{

     "id": "fund",
      "in": "bank",
      "out": "bank",
      "value": 10
}]
 //if(radio 1(trans) is bank and radio 2(fund) is credit)

 [{
      "id": "trans",
      "in": "bank",
      "out": "bank",
      "value": 10
    },
  {
      "id": "fund",
      "in": "credit",
      "out": "bank",
      "value": 10
    }]
```

Comment: `document.querySelector('input[name="sending"]:checked').val‌​ue` or `$('input[name="sending"]:checked').val()`

Comment: it would be less painful if we could have a view on the html part concerned

Comment: what is `${obj.map.function((e)=>{  <div class="form-check" ` ?  this is not jQuery syntax

Comment: @MrJ thanks for reply, I have used litelement